# Can Chomsky Normal Form have more than one terminal?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, automata

In formal language theory, a context-free grammar G is said to be in Chomsky normal form  if
$$ S → A B$$
$$ A → a $$
$$S → ε $$

My question is that if $B$ in the the form of
$$ B → abcd $$

where $abcd$ are terminal symbol, is this still in Chomsky Normal Form? ?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form) gives a definition of Chomsky normal form. Next time, I suggest consulting Wikipedia first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above given CFG cannot be in Chomsky Normal Form since the production 
B→abcd has multiple terminals on left hand side of the production.
In order to convert the given CFG to Chomsky Normal Form, will need to replace the terminals on lhs of production B→abcd as follows - 
B->abcd
B->FG
F->AE
G->CD
E->b
C->c
D->d.